# how to call scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval without a timer variable

Tags: nstimer

Would like to remove the warning that timer is not being used in...

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(loadSeries:) userInfo:_response repeats: NO];
```

I found a discussion which suggested using...

```
 NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: @selector(loadSeries:), userInfo: _response, repeats: false)
```

That, howver, returns errors that NSTimer doesnt have the property scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval and that Target is undeclared.

Cannot find any way to create the timer without the dangling timer variable.

Thanks,

John

Comment: First code is Objective-C. Second code is Swift. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(loadSeries:) userInfo:_response repeats: NO];
```

...just delete the assignment.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(loadSeries:) userInfo:_response repeats: NO];
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks. I am confused a bit now, however, I have this exact timer call in a couple of other places and other similar calls all of which make the assighment. The Analyzer is not complaining about the other assignments not being used. Which begs a few questions.  1. Why aren't they generating a warning.  2. They work without complaint with or without the assignments, should I remove the assignment on all the others as well?  3. Why does scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval return a value in the first place? When would you ever use the assignment?

Comment: timer is a static variable defined at the top of the implentation file with "static NSTimer *timer;". scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval is called in several methods all within the same implementtion file but only 2 of them were flagged by the Analyzer. None are repeating timers.I don't see any difference in how or where they are called. Thanks for your answers. Since I am not using timer at all and to be consistent I removed the variable all together in this implementation file. Now that I understand this a bit better I think I understand when I need to use a declared variable. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my last comment. No problem. You answered my question, which to me was important to further my understanding of Xcode.